# Printing a query from a database

Tags: java, hsqldb

I am trying to access a database and print off a query.
I am trying to access a DEVICE table and print off the DEVICE_ID, but i am unsuccessful so far.

Here is my code at the moment;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver");

        Preferences sysRoot = Preferences.systemRoot();
        Preferences prefs = sysRoot.node("com/davranetworks/zebu");
        url = prefs.get("dburl", "jdbc:hsqldb:E:\\eem\\eemdb");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Connection c = getConnection();

    try {
        c.setAutoCommit(true);
        Statement s = c.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM eem_db.device");

        ResultSet deviceId = s.executeQuery("select device_id from eem_db.device");
        System.out.println(deviceId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection() {
    Connection c = null;
    try {
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error initialising connection" + e);
    }
    return c;
}
```

The returned value is `org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCResultSet@1d3d68df`.
I don't know what this value relates to as I was expecting 3 integer values.
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You really could have just googled for `JDBCResultSet`. Here's an example: http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/jdbc/jdbcresultset.html

Comment: You're printing the object instance itself, not the result set, which is the type of the object.  Look up how to iterate over a result set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over the rows contained in the ResultSet and for each row get the column you want:

```
ResultSet deviceIdRS = s.executeQuery("select device_id from eem_db.device");
while(deviceIdRS.next()) {
    System.out.println(deviceIdRS.getString("device_id"));
}
```

You must use the ResultSet getXXX method that correspond with your column type, for example, getInt, getString, getDate...

Answer (score 0):

You are printing object of ResultSet, it won't give you the right values.
You need to iterate the loop like below

```
while(deviceId.next()) {
    int integerValue = deviceId.getInt(1);
    System.out.println("content" + integerValue)
}
deviceId.close();
s.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

That `ResultSet deviceId` is actually an object contains rows of result from your sql, so you only can see the memory address when you print it out.
You need something like:

```
while(deviceId.next()){
     System.out.print(deviceId.getInt(1));         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`s.executeQuery("select device_id from eem_db.device");` is returning a resultSet, you must find out the value from result set. 
like

> int device_id = resultset["deviceId"];

Answer (score 0):

```
 while (deviceId.next()) 
 {
    // Printing results to the console
      System.out.println("device_id- "+ deviceId.getInt("device_id");

 }
```

iterate object using resultset.